Location usage description on WatchOS exclusive app
My app is being rejected arguing it needs to add the location permission usage description when asked. It is a watchOS only app and there's no iPhone counterpart.
I have two info.plist files. One in the WatchKit app target and the other in the WatchKit Extension target. I need to add the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key to both of them in order to see the message appearing on permission requesting. If I delete it from the App target, the app shows the request without the additional description. If I delete it from the extension, there's no request at all. So I need both and that works as intended but when I submit the archive to Apple it gives me an error saying the usage description keys should not be on the WatchKit App's info.plist. I'm very confused. I've tried to add different location usage keys to the extension but it does nothing without adding them to the app too. Any help would be appreciated.
EDIT: Tried David Pasztor answer and triple checked every step but it didn't worked :( I can't believe there's no information about this issue from Apple. It seems to be a common question for many people since this is more an Apple bug than a poor implementation.

This Apple developer forums answer might help. It is about HealthKit usage description key, but the same solution should work for location as well.

Wow! That seems exactly what I need. Thank you very much!
